# Pyspark pandas_udf error with integer return values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pandas-udf

I am currently learning about `pandas_udf` in pyspark. Here is my spark dataframe:

```
import pyspark
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import  StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType


spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName('Tmp').master('local').getOrCreate()


df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 'Europe', 'France'),
                            (2, 'Asia', 'China'),
                            (3, 'Africa', 'Egypt'),
                            (4, 'Asia', 'India')], ['id', 'Continent', 'Country'])

df.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+---+---------+-------+                                                         
|id |Continent|Country|
+---+---------+-------+
|1  |Europe   |France |
|2  |Asia     |China  |
|3  |Africa   |Egypt  |
|4  |Asia     |India  |
+---+---------+-------+
```

I created a function named as `dummy_func_string` which returns a basic pandas series of string values and used that function to create a `pandas_udf` to add a new column in the dataframe:

```
def dummy_func_string(x):
    return pd.Series(['1', '2', '3', '4'])

string_udf = pandas_udf(dummy_func_string, ArrayType(StringType()))

df.withColumn('UDF_String', string_udf(col('country'))).show()
```

```
+---+---------+-------+----------+                                              
| id|Continent|Country|UDF_String|
+---+---------+-------+----------+
|  1|   Europe| France|       [1]|
|  2|     Asia|  China|       [2]|
|  3|   Africa|  Egypt|       [3]|
|  4|     Asia|  India|       [4]|
+---+---------+-------+----------+
```

This part above works fine, but when I try to create a `pandas_udf` using a function that returns integer value pandas series instead of string, I am getting an error:

```
def dummy_func_integer(x):
    return pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])

integer_udf = pandas_udf(dummy_func_integer, ArrayType(IntegerType()))

df.withColumn('UDF_Integer', integer_udf(col('country'))).show()
```

This is the error:

```
24/02/11 22:29:20 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 9)/ 1]
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4904, in apply
    ).apply()
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1427, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1507, in apply_standard
    mapped = obj._map_values(
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 921, in _map_values
    return algorithms.map_array(arr, mapper, na_action=na_action, convert=convert)
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 1743, in map_array
    return lib.map_infer(values, mapper, convert=convert)
  File "lib.pyx", line 2972, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/pandas/types.py", line 814, in convert_array
    assert isinstance(value, Iterable)
AssertionError

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:572)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
24/02/11 22:29:20 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 9) (172.31.5.103 executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4904, in apply
    ).apply()
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1427, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1507, in apply_standard
    mapped = obj._map_values(
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 921, in _map_values
    return algorithms.map_array(arr, mapper, na_action=na_action, convert=convert)
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 1743, in map_array
    return lib.map_infer(values, mapper, convert=convert)
  File "lib.pyx", line 2972, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/pandas/types.py", line 814, in convert_array
    assert isinstance(value, Iterable)
AssertionError

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:572)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

24/02/11 22:29:20 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 9.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 959, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 185, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4904, in apply
    ).apply()
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1427, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1507, in apply_standard
    mapped = obj._map_values(
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 921, in _map_values
    return algorithms.map_array(arr, mapper, na_action=na_action, convert=convert)
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 1743, in map_array
    return lib.map_infer(values, mapper, convert=convert)
  File "lib.pyx", line 2972, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/home/skapil/virtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/pandas/types.py", line 814, in convert_array
    assert isinstance(value, Iterable)
AssertionError
```

Can someone please help me understand when the function return string values, the code works fine, but when integer values are returned, there is an error?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) the input of a Pandas Udf should be always a Series, (Pandas) Dataframe or an iterator. The first udf also fails for me.